# Transformar Exchange Object a JSON en Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, exchangewebservices

tengo el siguiente escenario, tengo un metodo que recibe un objeto Exchange que en el Body trae una informacion como la mostrada en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito pasar dicha informacion a un JSON para convertirla a un Objeto de Java, pero cuando lo intento no lo logro por que la informacion no esta en una estructura JSON

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenia entendido que lo podía lograr con el siguiente código pero como no tiene una estructura JSON me da error al momento de serializar los datos

```
String jsonContent = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
List<LicensesAvailable> data = mapper.readValue(jsonContent, new TypeReference<List<LicensesAvailable>>() {});
```

Alguien me podria ayudar con el tema. Gracias.

Comment: Si puedes revisa la libreria de google GSON. Es muy util para lo que tienes alli. Tambien existen paginas web para mapear tu json a un objeto java. Simplifica el proceso. Tambien te sugiero que tu JSON este bien escrito. Puedes verlo aca
https://jsonviewer.stack.hu/     Si aun tienes problemas, puedo apoyarte pero necesitaria una muestra de tu archivo json para verlo.

Comment: Hola, es buen enfoque usar Jackson para este proposito funciona bastante bien, sin embargo te aconsejo que agregues el código correspondiente para poderte ayudar, minimo el string resultante para poder generar una respuesta  que te funcione.